# Update a TextView through a outer java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, server

I am currently working on a project and the following situation appeared: I have a ClientSide (of a server) with two threads and a TextView. I would like to display messages in TextView when the ClientSide receives them. I am currently using this code here:  http://www.nakov.com/inetjava/lectures/part-1-sockets/InetJava-1.10-Chat-client-server.html

My TextView has an id of textView, the java class is called ClientSide and it's 1:1 with the one from the link. I tried the following:
 - in the TextDataTransmitter thread, in its `run()` - `R.id.textView.setText(data)`. This pops me out cannot resolve setText
 `data` as you can see in the code is defined as a String.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call setText on the TextView object, not on its id.  Get the view by calling findViewById(R.id.textView) on the Activity after setContentView has been called.

Answer (score 1):

R.id.textView is the id of your TextView which is a `long`, your should get the textView by findViewById(R.id.textView) first.
AND don't modify UI object in non-main thread.